# Mule comparing map keys in choice

Tags: mule

I have a Map payload and I'm using *foreach* to get the key/value pair to further process in the flow.

**Example map payload:**
{key1=[org.myorg.domain.MyObj@7d9bae39, org.myorg.domain.MyObj@2a23741b],
key2=[org.myorg.domain.MyObj@7d9abd39, org.myorg.domain.MyObj@23de741b]}

**and a choice inside of it to direct it to the appropriate subflow as follows:**

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload.key1 == 'key1']">
            <flow-ref name="subflow_1" doc:name="one"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[message.payload.key2 == 'key2']">
            <flow-ref name="subflow_2" doc:name="two"/>
        <when expression="#[message.payload.key3 == 'key3']">
            <flow-ref name="subflow_3" doc:name="three"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="no match, default #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="payload"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</foreach>
```

**My question**
How do I match the key to go to the correct subflow. I keep getting the default/otherwise option as it's not matching on the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is evaluated against the map entry value not the key itself. If you want to check that a map contains a specific key, you could use the keySet or  you could just use a simple null check :

```
 <when expression="#[payload.keySet().contains('key1')]">
```

or

```
 <when expression="#[message.payload['key1'] != null]">
```

Comment: I've tried the first option since I need to know in the choice which subflow to continue, however, I'm getting an exception that the message payload is a HashSet and that's because my payload is  Map<String, HashSet<MyObj>

Comment: Didn't get my whole comment, sorry  I've tried the first option since I need to know in the choice which subflow to continue, however, I'm getting an exception that the message payload is a HashSet and that's because my payload is  `Map<String, HashSet<MyObj>>`  The foreach (I'm guessing) passes the value of the map to the next processor and that's why the logic on the choice will not work.

Comment: Finally got it to work using a flowVars. As I mention before I think when you use _foreach_ with payload (the default) it loops through the values of each key and I needed the key as well to determine the subflow. 
Ryan, I used your idea so I'm you get credit for it, thank you.

`<foreach collection="#[flowVars.myvar]" doc:name="For Each"> 
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
             <when expression="#[myvar.keySet().contains('key1')]">
                    <flow-ref name="mysub" doc:name="subflow"/>
                </when>`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a more elegant solution to this without having to use choice. Flow-ref accepts a mule expression to be the flow name i.e:

```
<flow-ref name="#[payload.key]" />
```

You could match the flow names according to the keys and it would redirect it without having to add the choice.

Comment: I've tested your suggestion and when you pass in the **key** it would look for a sub flow with the **value** name. My values are `Map<String, Set<EventInfo>>` so I don't think that would work. It works perfect when I tested with a simple map `Map<String, String>`, but how would this work for a complex map since the value is the ref-flow name it's looking to match.